# How to add a foreign key to string in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I pull data from semantic scholar and want to make many to many relationship where for example

- authorId: 144913779
- paperId: 6d41ef098cbe439a33535ce1a2399d2cec7508c1

are strings.

Author table:

```
class Author(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "author"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    authorId = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)  # semantic author id
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    affiliations = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=True)

    bib = db.relationship(
        'bibliography', secondary=bibliography, backref=db.backref('pages'))
```

Publication table:

```
class Publication(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "publication"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    paperId = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
```

Pivot table

```
bibliography = db.Table('bibliography', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('paperId', db.String(99), db.ForeignKey('publication.paperId')),
    db.Column('authorId', db.String(20), db.ForeignKey('author.authorId'))
```

Edits:

Added code.

I get errors:

- VARCHAR requires a length on dialect MySQL
- author table already exists

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot more useful to understand the problem. Could you also provide the code where you initialize the database? I suspect you're calling `db.create_all()` (or some other variant) each time your program runs

Comment: To me, it happens during migration on .....db upgrade. But regardless I think. I just need an example

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation of your code is correct?